# Move from temporary used in method chaining

Tags: c++, move, method-chaining, temporary-objects

I am trying to do something similar to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Bar
    {
    Bar& doThings()
        {return *this;}

    std::unique_ptr<int> m_content; // A non-copyable type
    };

struct Foo
    {
    Foo& append(Bar&& obj)
        {
        objects.push_back(std::move(obj));
        return *this;
        }

    std::vector<Bar> objects;
    };

int test()
    {
    Foo test;
    test.append(std::move(Bar{}.doThings())) //Ok
    // Not ok
      .append(Bar{}.doThings())
        ;
    }
```

> **error:** cannot bind rvalue reference of type `Bar&&` to lvalue of type `Bar`

Is it possible to make this work without the explicit std::move?

Trying to overload doThings does not solve the problem:

> **error:** `Bar&& Bar::doThings() &&` cannot be overloaded

Comment: The only way to get this to work without an explicit `move` is to return by value from `doThings`.

Comment: @NathanOliver ... or append somthing else.

Comment: Yes, your code can be changed in dozens of ways to make it compile without a `std::move`.   But the problem is your code, as written, doesn't compile.  Without a description *outside of your code* saying *what you want it to do*, any changes will *change what your code does* with *zero guidance about what you want it to do*.  Which in extreme means changing your code to `int main(){}` would make it compile.  Sure, the program is different, but so is *any* change to your code.  Why does `append` take `Bar&&`?  Why does `doThings` return `Bar&`?  Why call `doThings` at all?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The code does compile, though. The code inside of `test` is there as an example, showing what the OP wants, so it doesn't have to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add ref-qualified overloads of `doThings()`:

```
struct Bar
    {
    Bar& doThings() &
        {return *this;}

    Bar&& doThings() &&
        {return std::move(*this);}

    std::unique_ptr<int> m_content; // A non-copyable type
    };
```

Comment: Returning `&&` is dangerous and alnost always a bad idea; code that would usually reference lifetime extend temporaries doesn't work on `&&` return values.  Of course, the alternative here is also bad, so...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont In this case, though, returning `&&` is the right thing. See [`std::optional::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value), for example

Comment: @Justin Adding an extra overload is apparently ambiguous in this case

Comment: @user877329 Notice how I ref-qualified both member functions. You have to ref-qualify every member function, not just the one `&&` overload you add

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you return the instance from the function, you don't have an rvalue.

However, there is a way to overload functions based on the rvalue/lvalue of the object:

```
 Bar& doThings() & {return *this;}
 Bar doThings() && {return std::move(*this); }
```

Comment: The downside here is that `doThings` becomes a "do something, then permit chaining" and becomes "do something, create an object, move into that object, destroy that new object".  That could be mildly surprising; on the other hand, it is operating on an rvalue, and  unless your move ctor is broken it shouldn't matter much.